# Excel if column is hidden a diffrent columns cell equals text

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is there a way to have a cell return a value if a column is hidden,

Example - if column "A" is hidden cell "B1" would equal "text"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place this formula in cell B1.

```
=If(CELL("width",A1)=0,"Text","")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example where A1 is the cell that will be hidden, and B1 is the "else" part of the if statement

```
=IF(CELL("width",A1)=0,A1,B1)
```

the only problem with this is it wont auto-update (you have to hit F9 to have excel re-execute the formulas in order for it to work).  Or if its just that one cell, you can just click in the formula and hit enter again and it should calculate.  You could avoid this using macros, don't know how far you want to take it.

Hope this helped!